# Integrating Tinybox and Tipsy

Tags: jquery

In index page I have:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        T$('signup').onclick = function() {
            TINY.box.show('externalpage.html', 1, 450, 360, 1)
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

In external page, I have:

```
<a href="#" id="link" title="link tooltip/tipsy value">Link</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('#link').tipsy({gravity: 'n'});
    });
</script>
```

I know this is not correct but I think you know what I mean. So how to make it work?

Comment: What's `T$`? Also what's *not* working, what error are you getting in your console?

Comment: T$ is default from Tinybox. Whatever javascript function I put below the HTML in external page won't be run, except I call it from onClick for instance.

Comment: Did you also include a link to the jQuery library and Tipsy plugin in the external page?

Comment: I tried both including it or not, didn't work.

Comment: Does a simple `alert('hi');` show up when placed within the document-ready function in externalpage.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the external HTML page is part of extended elements of your existed calling page therefore the code you put on your external HTML will not be executed unless you use JQuery live() method to bind events in your external page.  For more details here is the link: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Happy coding....